# How to make vim to show errors in a new buffer?

Tags: vim

I am using vim for competitive programming and I am using this shell script to compile my c++ files.

```
g++ -static -DLOCAL -lm -s -x c++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -std=c++17 -o $1 $1.cpp
```

When I use this script I get all the errors and warnings in the terminal and when I press ENTER everything is gone. Is there a way to modify this script to display errors and warnings in a separate buffer in vim without going to terminal or is there anything that I should add in my .vimrc file ??

[image: check screenshot here]

I want my vim to show errors like this one below.

[image: check screenshot here]

Comment: Possibly dup, or at least of interest:  https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28759/how-can-i-compile-cpp-using-vim

Comment: I suggest learning how to use your tools before even thinking about using them in a competition: `:help user-manual`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by doing this

`nnoremap <F9> :wa <bar> :compiler gcc <bar> :silent! make %:r <CR> :cw <CR>`

But I don't know how to highlight errors of quickfix list.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing it. The best way, IMHO, would be to use the compiler plugins. Please read `:help compiler`. After that please read `:help make`. Here is an example from my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <F6> :wa <bar> :compiler cargo <bar> :make build <CR>
```

The example is for Rust. In your case it would be like this

```
nnoremap <F6> :wa <bar> :compiler gcc <bar> :make<CR>
```